# Criar ulilizador com password encriptada

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Tenho duvidas em relação ao Laravel uma das quais reflete-se onde inserir o campo:

```
$password = hash::make('password');
```

Visto que quero encriptar a *password* do formulário de criação do utilizador.

O código da *View* é:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'users.store')) }}
<li>
   {{ Form::label('password', 'Confirmar Password:') }}
   {{ Form::password('password_confirmation') }}
</li>
{{Form::close()}}
```

Do *Controller* é:

```
public function store()
    {
        $input = Input::all();
        $validation = Validator::make($input, User::$rules);

        if ($validation->passes())
        {
            User::create($input);

            return Redirect::route('users.index');
        }

        return Redirect::route('users.create')
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validation)
            ->with('message', 'Existem erros de validação.');
    }
```

Como fazer este passo na minha aplicação?

<sup>*Fiz a [mesma pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26490233/create-a-user-with-hashed-password)*.</sup>

Comment: tavares, não precisa avisar lá no SO que duplicou aqui, a política lá é outra. E se tiver resposta lá antes que aqui, pode colocar aqui a solução (de preferência com suas próprias palavras) e citar a fonte também. Boa sorte!

Answer (score 1):

coloque o código depois da validação, ficaria algo parecido com isso

```
if ($validation->passes())
{
    $input['password_confirmation'] = hash::make($input['password_confirmation']);

    User::create($input);

    return Redirect::route('users.index');
}
```

Ai estamos criptografando o que foi digitado pelo usuário e adicionando a variável input, já que é ela que você passou ela como parâmetro para criar o usuário

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($validation->passes())
{
    $user = new User;

    $user->username = Input::get('username');
    $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));

    $user->save();

    return Redirect::route('users.index');
}
```

Penso que seja isto que precisas, é umas das maneiras correctas em Laravel 4.